# Вывод из БД php

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, как можно вывести из БД и вывести все эти данные вне зоне while?

В базе есть 52456 строки, надо вывести всё и отобразить в блок, которые находиться за while.

```
        $usersfriendsmini = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id='$friendusmini[idUser]' OR id='$friendusmini[idFriend]') AND id not like '%$_GET[id]%'");
        while ($userfriendmini = mysql_fetch_array($usersfriendsmini)) {
                    if ($userfriendmini[avatar] == '0') {
                        $userfriendminiav = 'user.png';
                    } else {
                        $userfriendminiav = "avatars/".$userfriendmini[avatar];
                    }
                    $friendbl = "<a href='/profile/".$userfriendmini[id]."/'><img src='/images/".$userfriendminiav."' title='".$userfriendmini[surname]." ".$userfriendmini[name]."' class='avatar'></a>";
        }



<div class='test'><?php echo $friendbl; ?></div>
```

Проблема состоит именно в том, что он выводит не всё, а только одну запись, а точнее первую, которая выводиться. Мне надо, чтобы выводило всё.

Пробовал без while, но без while он только 1 запись и выводит...

Я думаю, что проблема из-за того, что она стоит в переменной, так как переменная хватает первую запись и выводит только её. Может можно как-то заменить её?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как насчет [буферизации выходного потока](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php

ob_start();

$usersfriendsmini = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id='$friendusmini[idUser]' OR id='$friendusmini[idFriend]') AND id not like '%$_GET[id]%'");

while ($userfriendmini = mysql_fetch_array($usersfriendsmini)) {
if ($userfriendmini[avatar] == '0') {
    $userfriendminiav = 'user.png';
} else {
    $userfriendminiav = "avatars/".$userfriendmini[avatar];
}

echo "<a href='/profile/".$userfriendmini[id]."/'><img src='/images/".$userfriendminiav."' title='".$userfriendmini[surname]." ".$userfriendmini[name]."' class='avatar'></a>";
}

$friendbl = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

?>

<div class='test'><?php echo $friendbl; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так вы на каждой итерации цикла перезаписываете значение переменной $friendbl. Сохраняйте записи в массив, т.е. каждый новый элемент массива - это одна запись.

```
$usersfriendsmini = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id='$friendusmini[idUser]' OR id='$friendusmini[idFriend]') AND id not like '%$_GET[id]%'");

$friendbl = array();
while ($userfriendmini = mysql_fetch_array($usersfriendsmini)) {
    if ($userfriendmini[avatar] == '0') {
        $userfriendminiav = 'user.png';
    } else {
        $userfriendminiav = "avatars/".$userfriendmini[avatar];
    }
    $friendbl[] = "<a href='/profile/".$userfriendmini[id]."/'><img src='/images/".$userfriendminiav."' title='".$userfriendmini[surname]." ".$userfriendmini[name]."' class='avatar'></a>";
}
```

Выводите так же через цикл:

```
foreach ($friendbl as $v) {
    echo $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместите `echo $friendbl` в конец цикла.

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Мне нужно, чтобы этот вывод был после всего этого. 
Так как я сейчас делаю строение 
php сверху, а html снизу

Comment: Тогда может    
`$friendbl = $friendbl + "<a href='/profile/".$userfriendmini[id]."/'><img src='/images/".$userfriendminiav."' title='".$userfriendmini[surname]." ".$userfriendmini[name]."' class='avatar'></a>";`

Comment: Работает, но вывод не корректный...http://prntscr.com/c5swex

Comment: Так. Разобрался. 
Вместо "+" поставил "."

Comment: @СашаОсипов Используйте сокращённую запись `"$friendbl .= "строка";` вместо `$friendbl = $friendbl . "строка";`. Код будет легче читать. [Строковые операторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)